# html_entity_decode for php 3

Tags: php

I have php 3.2.1 and want to decode html tags for example `&lt;` or `&gt;` I know of html_entity_decode in php 4 and above but not sure what do you for PHP 3?

Comment: Whoa, a  fossil!

Comment: Perhaps you might think of updating your PHP version...

Comment: [PHP_Compat](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat/redirected) or [upgradephp](http://upgradephp.berlios.de/) or look into the manuals comment section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred solution would be to upgrade PHP so that it doesn't make your hair stand on end when you hear what version it is...

Other than that, you 'd have to implement your own given a [list of HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), a loop and `str_replace`. Even then you 'd have another possible problem: encodings (PHP 3 doesn't offer any encoding conversion support, so you 'd have to code that too if you need it).

Answer (score 1):

If you're still on php 3.2.1, a version that is about 10 years old and no longer supported, you are doing something fundamentally wrong. Running an application on such an old, unsupported piece of infrastructure is a huge risk!